# Why does a Snowflake Filter<>'Condition' also filters NULLs?

Tags: sql

In our payment transactions table, we categorize each record thusly

```
  case 
    when TYPE = 'PTT.N' then 'Authentication'
    when TYPE = 'PTT.R' then 'Rebill'
    when TYPE = 'PTT.U' then 'Update'
    when TYPE = 'PTT.C' then 'Cancel'
    when TYPE = 'PTT.M' then 'Migration'
    when TYPE is null then 'Order'
    else TYPE
  end
```

We access this production table via a view and because of a business rule change, I had to rebuild it to filter  'PTT.M' records out. It worked but to my surprise, it also filtered records where TYPE is null. This is the code for the view:

```
with source as (
    select 
      ...
    from  payments
    left join payment_service ON payments.PAYMENT_SERVICE = payment_service.ID
),

renamed as (

  SELECT
      ID as payment_id,
      zeroifnull(AMOUNT) AS amount,
      SERVICE_PAYER_IDENTIFIER,
      CREATION_DATE,
...
      case 
        when TYPE = 'PTT.N' then 'Authentication'
        when TYPE = 'PTT.R' then 'Rebill'
        when TYPE = 'PTT.U' then 'Update'
        when TYPE = 'PTT.C' then 'Cancel'
        when TYPE = 'PTT.M' then 'Migration'
        when TYPE is null then 'Order'
        else TYPE 
      end as type,
...
  from source
)

select * from renamed where type<>'PTT.M';
```

This is confusing. A NULL is not a string. My WHERE clause `where type<>'PTT.M'` was simply doing a string compare so would NULLs be filtered out too? Can someone please explain?

Thank you.

PS: I modified the WHERE clause thusly `ifnull(type, '') <> 'PTT.M'` to resolve this. That way, I just do a string comparison.

Comment: Surely this should be `where type <> 'Migration'` - what happens if you give your column a different alias that's not the same as the column name. Using `NULL` (ie *unknown*) to represent a *known* value is a flaw, when comparing a column with an inequality, NULL will be removed since it's *uknown*, a null is neither equal nor not equal to a value.

Comment: You should have the mappings in table instead, and join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<>` and `=` treats NULLs as unknown values. Use [`IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from) instead.

From Docs :

> Compares whether two expressions are equal (or not equal). The
> function is `NULL-safe`, meaning it treats NULLs as known values for
> comparing equality

```
SELECT *
FROM renamed
WHERE type IS DISTINCT FROM 'PTT.M';
```

Comment: I learned something today. Thank you. Accepted and voted up.